# Google Maps API / JavaScript: How to find out base point / lowest point of custom marker to set as anchor point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I use the following function to create a (basic) custom marker for the Google maps API. Everything works except that the markers slightly change position when zooming.
I assume that this is caused by the default anchor point.

How can I find out what is the base point (lowest point) of my specific marker so that I can set this as my anchor point ?

```
function createMarker(fillColor) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0, 0 C -2, -20 -10, -22 -10, -30 A 10, 10 0 1, 1 10, -30 C 10, -22 2, -20 0, 0 z',
        fillColor: fillColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        labelOrigin: { x: 0, y: -29 },
        scale: 1.2,
        strokeColor: '#fff',
        strokeWeight: 1
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your marker's anchor isn't correct as is (the default is (0,0))?  It looks right to me (although the marker has a pretty "sharp" point). [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/aw37fgj0/1/), the red "measle" markers are at the specified coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an SVG icon, by default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in the same coordinate system as the symbol's path."

> [anchor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Symbol.anchor)
> **Type:**  Point optional
> The position of the symbol relative to the marker or polyline. The coordinates of the
> symbol's path are translated left and up by the anchor's x and y coordinates
> respectively. By default, a symbol is anchored at (0, 0). The position is expressed in
> the same coordinate system as the symbol's path.

For your path: `'M 0, 0 C -2, -20 -10, -22 -10, -30 A 10, 10 0 1, 1 10, -30 C 10, -22 2, -20 0, 0 z'`, that looks correct to me.

To change it, set the `anchor` property as described above.

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,-30)
```

will put the center of the "bubble" over the coordinates.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/aw37fgj0/3/)

with the default of `(0,0)`:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/aw37fgj0/1/)